# OpenGL ES 2.x: How to read pixels after glDiscardFramebufferEXT?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I read [EXT_discard_framebuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_discard_framebuffer.txt) which causes the contents of the named framebuffer attachable images to become undefined. And after discard framebuffer, the pixel value from glReadPixels are same as before discard framebuffer. why? And, with this extension, an OpenGL ES implementation how to optimize away the storing back of framebuffer contents after rendering the frame?

```
//
// create a texture object
//
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//
// create a framebuffer object
//
GLuint fbo;
GLboolean check;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

check = glIsFramebuffer(fbo1);
if (!check) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "debug",
            "------ check Framebuffer object failed ------\n");
    return EGL_FALSE;
}

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "debug",
            "------ fbo not set completely!------\n");
    return EGL_FALSE;
}

draw_texture(fbo);

GLubyte sampledColor[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int randX = 128, randY = 128;

GLenum attachments[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT };
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glReadPixels(randX, randY, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sampledColor);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "debug",
    "[LINE: %d] coordinate(%d, %d) color is (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n",
    __LINE__, randX, randY, sampledColor[0], sampledColor[1],
    sampledColor[2], sampledColor[3]);

glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 2, attachments);

glReadPixels(randX, randY, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sampledColor);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "debug",
    "[LINE: %d] coordinate(%d, %d) color is (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n",
    __LINE__, randX, randY, sampledColor[0], sampledColor[1],
    sampledColor[2], sampledColor[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Job of glDiscardFramebufferEXT is to inform driver that you don't care about contents of framebuffer. What driver (or GPU) decides to do with it - it's not up to you. Driver can reset all contents to 0, or it can leave as it is, or maybe it will use this information when you will next call glClear and will perform it more efficiently (for example by allocating new memory for contents, instead of performing memset with 0 value). Don't worry about that what it will do exactly.

Comment: hi, Mārtiņš Možeiko
i want to test glDiscardFramebufferEXT(), but i don't know what next step is after invoking glDiscardFramebufferEXT. you can show me? thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean - next step?

Comment: I want to test glDiscardFramebufferEXT func in Opengl ES2, how to check the function using correct, how to verify it?

Comment: Try measuring performance with and without Discard. With Discard performance should be not lower that without (but not necessarily higher).

Comment: ok, thank you very much, i will try it. BTW, could you give me some sample codes?

Comment: Sample code for measuring performance with and without Discard.

Comment: There is nothing much to show. Just get current time, perform your operation - drawing frame, get time again, and calculate difference in time. And do it again with different operation.